# Mod_rewrite on Nginx?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to install GitList (http://gitlist.org/) on my Nginx server. However, part of the installation is that I change the Apache config file with the following code:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    # Other lines omitted
    AllowOverride All
    # Other lines omitted
</Directory>
```

Furthermore, this is also needed in a `.htaccess` file inside the GitList folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /path/to/gitlist/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
<Files config.ini>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

How do I do this step in Nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is what needs to be added:

```
server {
    server_name MYSERVER;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/MYSERVER.access.log combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/MYSERVER.error.log error;

    root /var/www/DIR;
    index index.php;

#   auth_basic "Restricted";
#   auth_basic_user_file .htpasswd;

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~* ^/index.php.*$ {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        # if you're using php5-fpm via tcp
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        # if you're using php5-fpm via socket
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @gitlist;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
        expires max;
        try_files $uri @gitlist;
        tcp_nodelay off;
        tcp_nopush on;
    }

#   location ~* \.(git|svn|patch|htaccess|log|route|plist|inc|json|pl|po|sh|ini|sample|kdev4)$ {
#       deny all;
#   }

    location @gitlist {
        rewrite ^/.*$ /index.php;
    }
}
```